# Function for overriding the parent container of a div with position sticky?

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky, semantics

Created a html header and added two div in the header container. Now I want one div to stick to the top of the screen with position sticky.

It doesn't work unless I take the div out if the header container and set it to be a direct child of the body container but that would break the semantics of my html code. Is there a way to override it in CSS without having to move it in my html code so it sees the body as it's direct parent?

```css
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth font-family: "Inter", Sans-Serif;
  background-color: hsl(36, 100%, 99%);
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header_nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: hsl(36, 100%, 99%);
  width: 70vw;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: .75rem;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="./assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="header_img" />
    <div class="hamburger header_div"><span></span></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="header_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS please? Some guidance here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I wouldn't get so precious about having header stuff in the header tag - if it's the nav that you are wanting sticky, you could just rename it to site nav instead of header nav and move it outside the header tag.  If it's the other div then as your nav is display none, why not just make the header tag sticky (instead of trying to make the header div sticky)?

Comment: @Pete I just named the div with class header couldn't come up with something else at the moment..

Comment: @Pete because the header tag contains both the nav menu, logo and hamburger icon.

Comment: @Pete Okay I understand what you mean now. I just thought the navigation menu being in the header tag is part of HTML semantics.